# Chuck the plant - what am I?

Tags: identification, succulents

My name's Chuck, and I'm a plant.

[image]

I live indoors with my human flatmate.

**I'd like to know my species and scientific name**, but the human living with me seems pretty clueless - he never actually talks to me (plays me some good music though).

Can **you** tell me what I am?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sansevieria trifasciata laurentii is its unlovely botanical name, but it has the common names of Mother in Law's Tongue and Snake Plant too! Though you could just stick to Chuck...

It prefers bright light with a little sun, but will grow in shade too. Average temperatures with a minimum of 50degF in winter, water when the surface of the potting medium feels a little dry to the touch, don't leave it sitting in water in any outer tray or pot, reduce watering somewhat during winter.

Comment: And here is how you make Chucklets: https://www.joyusgarden.com/propagate-sansevierias-snake-plants/

Comment: Great stuff @Bamboo! Chuck has a follow up question if you have the time, I'll post it and link it here in a few minutes :)

Comment: @Bamboo and [here](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/31035/chuck-the-plant-am-i-ill) we go.